# Get the latest version of a product

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where I enter data of a product (SlobID) which is

```
SELECT        TemplateID, SlobID, FromYear, ToYear, MAX(ValidFrom) AS CurrentDate
FROM            CommissionsPerTemplate AS CommissionsPerTemplate_1
GROUP BY TemplateID, SlobID, FromYear, ToYear
HAVING        (MAX(ValidFrom) <= GETDATE()) AND (TemplateID = 2) AND (SlobID = 743)
```

the result I get is

```
TemplateID  SlobID  (From Year)  (To year)   Valid date
2            743        1          1        2016-01-01
2            743        1            99     2015-01-01
2            743        2            99     2016-01-01
```

the difficult part is that we need a query to get the latest version of this product. 
The 1st version (1/1/2015) if from year=1 to year=99
but 2nd version created on (1/1/2016) which splitter the years 
from year 1 to 1 and from year 2 to 99.

So the correct result for me should be the following

```
TemplateID  SlobID  (From Year)  (To year)   Valid date
2            743        1            1      2016-01-01
2            743        2            99     2016-01-01
```

but I have no idea on how to get this.
Perhaps on 1/1/2017 the new version should have from year =1 to year=10 and from year =11 to year =99 or something else.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything *extremely advanced* here.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a where clause

Comment: So you just want to get rid of the 1-99 record? Why? What if the 2-99 record was really 3-99? Then you're missing a 2-2 span. Would the 1-99 record then need to be reduced to a 2-2 with a `2015-01-01` date?

Comment: in this table we add constantly data. i can not do my task with where because i don't Know what data are added. my task is to get the most recent data (valid date ) of each SlobID for a unique period of years (From year - To Year)

Comment: Please edit your question title to something actually descriptive of the problem you're having or question you're asking. It should be something that will have relevance and meaning to a future reader who finds it in a list of search results. Your current title has absolutely no meaningful content; that it's about SQL and grouping is apparent from the tags you've added, and there is nothing useful (or accurate) in *extremely advanced*. Thanks.

Comment: dear Ken White , i can not figure out how to describe this problem with juts a title. sorry. but @kostya i think found the solution. If you have a good idea for the title i would be more than happy to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this will work for the rest of the data, but if you use row_number instead of group by and take out the "to year" from partition by it works for your sample data.

```
select * from 
(
SELECT        TemplateID, SlobID, FromYear, ToYear, ValidFrom As CurrentDate , row_number () over ( partition by TemplateID, SlobID,FromYear  order by ValidFrom desc) rowid
FROM            CommissionsPerTemplate AS CommissionsPerTemplate_1
where  (TemplateID = 2) AND (SlobID = 743)
) as x 
where rowid = 1
```

Comment: hm!!! it seems to work. but i can figure out the logic behind this. i will keep testing and letting you know